# Use of a Dialog box on Material Design

Tags: user-behavior, web-app, material-design

I'm designing a web app but can't reveal its name and its main function so let's see how this could be explained.

In this app there's a type of user that have the power to Add and Remove Team Members (Employees) so for him to do that I thought well let's make this very easy, he's just going to need to press the "+" button and fill a little form BUT to make it even more seamless let's make that a Dialog box.

Question: Is it right for an user to write stuff on a Dialog box or those are only for information display as alerts, etc.

Below you can enter the link to the Dialog section on Material Design and a screenshot of how this Dialog/Form is going to look (I need to add the lines below every line like any other form but I just stopped after this question popped right into my mind).

[image]

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#

Answer (score 1):

This is not clear in Material, kind of a grey zone. While you won't find any text edition example on a dialog, you will find other kind of forms in dialogs, specially on the [**Confirmation Dialogs**](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-confirmation-dialogs) sub-section. You'll notice there are all kind of form controls in dialogs, exception made of... text fields.

However, read this (bold font added to show you the important part):

> **Full-screen dialogs (Mobile only)**
>
> Full-screen dialogs are best suited to complex tasks, or **require an
>   input method editor**, as they group a series of tasks together before
>   they can be saved.

In general, Material prefers to have text fields on their own pages (and for this, you'll find loads of examples), and users have to navigate back after filling a form. Therefore, it would be a good idea to have your dialog include only a touch action, which would work like this:

---

**This area is restricted, please login**

[login] [cancel]

---

and then you could redirect the user to the form since they will need to do this only once.

However, moving aside of Material, this is common in iOS. For example, if you want to install an app, you'll have a dialog with some information like cost, and then you'll have a dialog where you will need to enter your password, as follows:

[image]

## In short

As long as you don't ask for this info every time, go for it. Otherwise, this is not a good idea since dialogs are interruptive

Comment: Now you got me thinking, a Dialog Box could be a pain in the rear end - lol -  but if the user has to go to another page just for a 3 lines form it could be a bitter experience too.... Do you think an A/B Test is required to solve this problem?

Comment: As long as it is a one time thing (which it should be), going to another page or opening a dialog is exactly the same cost in terms of UX. If you´re app is an Android one, then your users will be used to it. If this is for iOS, use the dialog. Alternatively, you can use just a password field and and detect the username by its device

Answer (score 0):

In fact, in your example, in the image posted here, you have an example of [Confirmation dialog](https://material.google.com/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-confirmation-dialogs). Even you have text fields, radio buttons or switch buttons, there is always a form and the user interact with it.

Maybe the blog was updated, but I find clear in the examples from [Material Design Blog](https://material.google.com/components/dialogs.html) that is ok "to write stuff on a Dialog box".

Here are some example from the blog:

[image]

[image]